# Multi-Cut Matrix Models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, string-theory

I have a question pertaining specifically to a one-matrix model with a multi-cut solution.  The standard procedure is to take a polynomial superpotential $W(x)$.  In the classical limit (analogous to $\hbar =0$), all of the eigenvalues are sitting precisely at the extrema of $W$.  As you turn some sort of coupling on, and pass to the large-$N$ 't Hooft limit (the matrices are $N \times N$), the eigenvalues "repel" each other and spread out to form "branch cuts."

I had been assuming that this spreading out from the extrema of $W$ happens symmetrically, but perhaps they won't spread symmetrically if the eigenvalues from the other cuts can repel them?  To make my question more concrete, imagine just two extrema of $W$ at $\pm1$ on the real axis.  Let's assume the cuts will spread out also on the real axis.  Will each cut emerge *symmetrically* from $\pm1$?  Or will they actually spread more on the "outside" since the eigenvalues might repel each other more on the "inside"?

I haven't seen this discussed in the matrix model literature so I was hoping perhaps someone had some insight!